# Java - How to Swipe - AndroidDriver

Tags: java, selenium, appium, appium-android, java-client

i trying to swipe up inside my android app.
But its not working. I using java-client-8.0.0 and Selenium-server-4.1.2

I tryied allready:

```
TouchAction ta = new TouchAction(driver);
PointOption poStart = new PointOption();
PointOption poEnd = new PointOption();
poStart.point(656, 1393);
poEnd.point(437, 619);
ta.press(poStart).moveTo(poEnd).release().perform();
```

But TouchAction is deprecated.

How to scroll/swipe up on Android with Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for the problem.

Just use W3C Actions because the TouchAction is deprecated.
http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/interactions/actions/

Here a example for a swipe:

```
Point source = new Point(769, 309);
Point target = new Point(752, 2348);
PointerInput finger = new PointerInput(PointerInput.Kind.TOUCH, "finger");
Sequence swipe = new Sequence(finger, 1);
swipe.addAction(finger.createPointerMove(Duration.ofMillis(0),
                    PointerInput.Origin.viewport(), source.x, source.y));
swipe.addAction(finger.createPointerDown(PointerInput.MouseButton.LEFT.asArg()));
swipe.addAction(finger.createPointerMove(Duration.ofMillis(700),
                    PointerInput.Origin.viewport(),target.x, target.y));
swipe.addAction(finger.createPointerUp(PointerInput.MouseButton.LEFT.asArg()));
driver.perform(Arrays.asList(swipe));
```